# Docker: Could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among the defaults to assign to the network

Tags: docker, networking, docker-compose, docker-network

When I was trying to deploy my application with docker-compose I got back the following error:

```
Creating network "<myapplicationnamehere_mycustomnetwork>" with the 
default driver
could not find an available, non-overlapping IPv4 address pool among 
the defaults to assign to the network
```

Now I researched a bit here and there and people suggested to prune unused old docker networks with `docker network prune`. But since I am running 34 docker containers  (about ~30 networks I think), it only prunes one or two old networks before the error occurs again.

**My question is: How can I make sure I can run many services without running into docker network allocation problems. (Maybe create smaller subnets somehow?)**

My top-key network section of the docker-compose file looks as follows:

```
#
# Networks section
# Networks:
# - public, represents the network between nginx and the public nginx-proxy (which should be already running)
# - uwsgi, represents the network between nginx and uwsgi
# - postgres, represents the network between uwsgi and postgres
#
networks:
  uwsgi:
  postgres:
  public:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

Comment: Thank you for mentioning `docker network prune` in the question, this was exactly what I needed in my case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can know specify custom address ranges with the default-address-pool property since Docker 18.06. See also  [the associated Pull Request](https://github.com/moby/moby/pull/36396).